# Trying to create nested array within an Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created a loop, and it appears that I am unintentionally rewriting over an object property.

My code is the following:

```
Object.keys(existingComments1).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(existingComments1[key]['sectionId']);
    comment.sectionId = existingComments1[key]['sectionId'];
    existingComments.push(comment);
});

[{
    "sectionId": "3",
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": 66,
            "authorAvatarUrl": "support/images/clay_davis.png",
            "authorName": "Senator Clay Davis",
            "authorId": 3,
            "comment": "These Side Comments are incredible. Sssshhhiiiiieeeee."
        }
    ]
}];
```

When I look into the console I have the same `sectionId` value over and over again. In my mind, this should work perfectly, but I think I am missing something.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is `existingComments1 ` like and what result do you expect?

Comment: also what is `comment`? you use one object comment, and update it filed, so after loop you have array with many links to one object

Comment: Having trouble copying my objects here. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: possibly you need `existingComments.push({sectionId : existingComments1[key]['sectionId']})`

Comment: can you provide `existingComments1` also? and why you remove expected output? :-)

Comment: I am trying to make it look a bit better.

Comment: authorAvatarUrl: "images/profile/test123.55134350ac6956.23064912.jpg"
authorName: "test123"
comment: "working hard."
created_by: "38"
id: "30"
sectionId: "1200"

Comment: `existingComments1` is array or object?

Comment: existingComments1 are objects in the format of a JSON.

Comment: in OP you add `existingComments1` or expected `existingComments`?

Comment: insted _forEach_ methinks better use _map_ in your case

Comment: I wanted to revise the existingComments1  to resemble the out that you edited for me.  I have achieved that with the code that I displayed up above. The unfortunate problem I am experiencing is the section Id is being written over and that causes issues with displaying comments on my user's page.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with a map. Is there documentation or can you provide me with a small example?

Comment: mdn [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

I've inferred a few things about the environment around your code, but this fiddle works for me:

```
existingComments = []
existingComments1 = { foo: {sectionId: 1}, bar: {sectionId:3} }

Object.keys(existingComments1).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(existingComments1[key]['sectionId']);
  comment = {}
  comment.sectionId = existingComments1[key]['sectionId'];
  existingComments.push(comment);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e7z5btng/

Comment: That worked but it needs to be a certain format.                                                        {
        "sectionId": "3",
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": 66,
                "authorAvatarUrl": "support/images/clay_davis.png",
                "authorName": "Senator Clay Davis",
                "authorId": 3,
                "comment": "These Side Comments are incredible. Sssshhhiiiiieeeee."
            }
        ]
    }
];

Comment: Changing the data structure still seems to work:  https://jsfiddle.net/e7z5btng/1/